# How can I "comment" out an entire class in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am working on a project in Android Studio. I have a class in my project that I'm working on that isn't finished and doesn't compile. I don't have any other components of the project relying on that class, but I don't want to have to keep un/commenting the Java everytime I want to run my program or work on that class.

Is there a way to "hide" the entire class but still keep it in my project window? I am using Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to go to the "build.gradle" file for your app, and add in the following code:

```
sourceSets {
 main {
     java {
         exclude '/The name of your class.java'
     }
 }
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it out. I've a class `YettobuildClass.java` which is unfinished and i ignore them to build by adding,

```
sourceSets {
      main
         {
           java
               {
                   exclude '**/YettobuildClass.java'
               }
         }
    }
```

in the `build.gradle` file. Good luck!